# Extracting data-keyword= from <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm extracting data from a type class bs4.element.Tag, when I print the element.
I want to extract exclusively the "data-keyword=" part, so basically just the keyword, however unsuccessfully.

This is what I have already tried in addition to reading previous articles:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
keyList = ['a','b','c']
mainUrl = "https://www.amazon.com/"
browser.get(mainUrl)
searchInput = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="twotabsearchtextbox"]')
searchInput.clear()
for keyChar in keyList:
        time.sleep(2)
        searchSoup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
        searchResult = searchSoup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'suggestions-template'})
        results = searchResult[0].find_all('div', attrs={'class':'s-suggestion'})
        time.sleep(1)
        for x in results:
            print(x)
            print(type(x))
            narrow_down = x.find_all('div', attrs={'data-keyword:'})
            print(narrow_down)
```

This is what I get:

```
<div class="s-suggestion" data-alias="aps" data-crid="2D6LIH2IP11XU" data-isfb="false" data-issc="false" data-keyword="amazon gift cards" data-nid="" data-reftag="nb_sb_ss_i_1_1" data-store="" data-type="a9" id="issDiv0"><span class="s-heavy"></span>a<span class="s-heavy">mazon gift cards </span></div>
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
[]
```

How can I get to print just the data-keyword= ?

Comment: It would help if you included, in the question, example html where some tags meet your criteria and some don't.  Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [mcve], [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Thanks, noted, currently there is no html that satisfy my query, i'm trying to grab all the autocomplete suggestion in Amazon search box.

Comment: Don't you intend to actually enter a search term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to change type to str.
Once change type, extract sub string from it.
    new_str = str(x)